# Why is @Html.DisplayName and @Html.DisplayNameFor used for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I know that @Html.DisplayFor is used when we need to generate the appropriate html control that would correspond to the property in model. But what is @Html.DisplayName and @Html.DisplayNameFor used for?

Answer (score 0):

They grab the display name.. the thing you would see in a field's label.

```
Class Something

    <System.Component.DataAnnotations.Display(Name := "some long label")>
    Public Property LabelOne As String

    <System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("another long label")>
    Public Property LabelTwo As String

End Class
```

Both Attributes above are respected by `@Html.DisplayName` and `.DisplayNameFor`.

I am unsure if `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebDisplayNameAttribute` is supported or not.